# How to extract group from regular expression in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got this query and want to extract the value between the brackets.

```
select de_desc, regexp_substr(de_desc, '\[(.+)\]', 1)
from DATABASE
where col_name like '[%]';
```

It however gives me the value with the brackets such as "[TEST]". I just want "TEST". How do I modify the query to get it?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The third parameter of the REGEXP_SUBSTR function indicates the position in the target string (`de_desc` in your example) where you want to start searching.  Assuming a match is found in the given portion of the string, it doesn't affect what is returned.

In Oracle 11g, there is a sixth parameter to the function, that I think is what you are trying to use, which indicates the capture group that you want returned.  An example of proper use would be:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('abc[def]ghi', '\[(.+)\]', 1,1,NULL,1) from dual;
```

Where the last parameter `1` indicate the number of the capture group you want returned. Here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) to the documentation that describes the parameter.

10g does not appear to have this option, but in your case you can achieve the same result with:

```
select substr( match, 2, length(match)-2 ) from (
SELECT regexp_substr('abc[def]ghi', '\[(.+)\]') match FROM dual
);
```

since you know that a match will have exactly one excess character at the beginning and end.  (Alternatively, you could use RTRIM and LTRIM to remove brackets from both ends of the result.)

Comment: What's amazing is that 6th parameter is not mentioned in Oracle's official REGEXP_SUBSTR documentation. Thanks for pointing out it exists.

Comment: It looks like google will take you to old documentation for REGEXP_SUBSTR, but if you are able to find 11g documentation you can see the 6th parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303

Answer (score 27):

You need to do a replace and use a regex pattern that matches the whole string.

```
select regexp_replace(de_desc, '.*\[(.+)\].*', '\1') from DATABASE;
```

Comment: IMHO this is the simplest, easy to remember, more flexible and therefore the best way to do it.

Comment: I would caution anyone using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to get the capture group that if the pattern is not matched, Oracle will return the entire value, whereas the behavior you probably want is for it to return `null`.  For example, `REGEXP_REPLACE ('abcdefghi',  '.*\[(.+)\].*', '\1')` (pattern is not matched) returns `abcdefghi`.  This tripped me up once.

Comment: The problem here is that Oracle regexp does not provide a function to return the part of the string matched by a capturing group. You can try using a recursive query (select ... from tab connect by ...) but be awre of the potential performance issue.

Comment: To get around the problem @Jared mentions, you can do an "or everything" `|^.*$` capture. `regexp_replace(de_desc, '.*\[(.+)\].*|^.*$', '\1')`. If nothing is captured in capture group 1, then the entire string will be replaced with null.

Comment: I'm curious as to what kind of performance impact this alternating expression with the fallback will have. Generally speaking, using 'or' alternating in regular expressions is painful, at least when I analyze the required steps in regex101.