# Oracle regexp Misunderstanding

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I don't understand how to get 'nth match of pattern starting at end of string'. I've read, but cannot apply.

The column I'm working with is directory path names that look typically like:

```
I:\044\LOGFILE\aw_34\
```

I want to pull out the last directory name, and the 2nd to last. Using regexp_substr I am able to get the last directory using

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^\]+\\$')
```

I think what I'm asking here is: 'beginning at the end of the value in col_name, return the first instance of 1 or more non-backslash characters that lie between two backslashes'.

However, I'm not able to use any sensible combination of option parameters to get just the second folder name ('\LOGFILE\' in this example). I've tried:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^\]+\\$', 1, 2)
```

returns NULL. It seems I'm not actually asking 'start at the end of the string and find the second occurrence of the pattern'. So, I've resorted to matching the pattern of the two last folders:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^\]+\\[^\]+\\$')
```

then, wrapping this expression in a 2nd regex to get a match on a single folder beginning at the front.

That works, but doesn't help me understand the basic error in using

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^\]+\\$', 1, 2)
```

or another more 'direct' way of pulling out just the match I need ('\LOGFILE\' in this example). What's wrong?

Comment: +1 for well explained question

Answer (score 3):

To match the second to last folder, use a capture group...

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '(\\[^\]+\\)[^\]+\\$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

The last parameter says get the first capture group, which is the thing in the parentheses in the regex pattern.

And `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^]+\\$', 1, 2)` didn't work because `$` matches end of the string so there won't be a second match.

Comment: For whatever reason, I began thinking of '$' as meaning 'begin your search for my pattern at the end of the string', instead of 'must be at the end of the string'. The nonsense of my regex request should have been obvious. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '\\[^\]+\\$', 1, 2)` doesn't work because there are not two matches which end with the `$` end-of-string - there can be at most one such match (any other match isn't at the end of the string, by definition).

I would try something like

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '(\\[^\]+){2}\\$')
```

then extract the first part of that... Note this is slightly different than what you had.

Alternatively, in later versions of Oracle (from version 11g onwards) there are ways to use capturing groups - a sixth argument to `REGEX_SUBSTR`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759146/1967396 which leads to

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, '(\\[^\]+){2}\\$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

to give the "contents of the first capturing group" - which is "the thing in parentheses in my regex" - i.e. `\LOGIFLE` in your example (without the trailing `\` though... since that belongs to the "next match").