# Oracle SQL regex extraction

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have data as follows in a column

```
+----------------------+
|      my_column       |
+----------------------+
| test_PC_xyz_blah     |
| test_PC_pqrs_bloh    |
| test_Mobile_pqrs_bleh|
+----------------------+
```

How can I extract the following as columns?

```
+----------+-------+
| Platform | Value |
+----------+-------+
|   PC     |  xyz  |
|   PC     |  pqrs |
|  Mobile  |  pqrs |
+----------+-------+
```

I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Default first pattern occurrence for `platform`:

```
select regexp_substr(my_column, 'test_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)') as platform from table
```

Getting second pattern occurrence for `value`:

```
select regexp_substr(my_column, 'test_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)', 1, 2) as value from table
```

This isn't working, however. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Non-empty tokens

```
select  regexp_substr(my_column,'[^_]+',1,2)    as platform
       ,regexp_substr(my_column,'[^_]+',1,3)    as value

from    my_table
;
```

---

For possibly empty tokens

```
select  regexp_substr(my_column,'^.*?_(.*)?_.*?_.*$',1,1,'',1)  as platform
       ,regexp_substr(my_column,'^.*?_.*?_(.*)?_.*$',1,1,'',1)  as value

from    my_table
;
```

---

```
+----------+-------+
| PLATFORM | VALUE |
+----------+-------+
| PC       | xyz   |
+----------+-------+
| PC       | pqrs  |
+----------+-------+
| Mobile   | pqrs  |
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)` is greedy by nature, it will match all character including `_` character as well, so `test_(.*)` will match whole of your string. Hence further groups in pattern `_(.*)_(.*)` have nothing to match, whole regex fails. The trick is to match all characters excluding `_`. This can be done by defining a group `([^_]+)`. This group defines a negative character set and it will match to any character except for `_` . If you have better pattern, you can use them like `[A-Za-z]` or `[:alphanum]`. Once you slice your string to multiple sub strings separated by `_`, then just select 2nd and 3rd group.

ex:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( my_column,'(([^_]+))',1,2) as platform, REGEXP_SUBSTR( my_column,'(([^_]+))',1,3) as value from table;`

Note: AFAIK there is no straight forward method to Oracle to exact matching groups. You can use regexp_replace for this purpose, but it unlike capabilities of other  programming language where you can exact just group 2 and group 3. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle) link for example.