# regexp_substr to get String between a string value and pipe

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

need regexp_substr for finding a string value between a string and a pipe

Example 1

```
'blah,blah...|text=1234|nmbnxcm'
```

Result 1:

```
1234
```

Example 2

```
'test,test...|text=4321|testing'
```

Result 2

```
4321
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll get what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle) doesn't help, then please try this, assuming there is only one occurrence of what you want from the source string.

```
select to_number(regexp_substr('blah,blah...|text=1234|nmbnxcm', '|text=([0-9]+)|', 1, 1, null, 1))
from dual;
```

The to_number wouldn't be required but is a bit more intentional w.r.t. the given RE.