# POSIX ERE Regular expression to find repeated substring

Tags: regex, posix, oracle-sqldeveloper, regexp-substr, posix-ere

I have a set of strings containing a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 values in a format like this:

```
123;456;789
123;123;456
123;123;123
123;456;456
123;456;123
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression so I can find values repeated on the same string, so if you have `123;456;789` it would return `null` but if you had `123;456;456` it would return `456` and for `123;456;123` return `123`

I managed to write this expression:

```
(.*?);?([0-9]+);?(.*?)\2
```

It works in the sense that it returns `null` when there are no duplicate values but it doesn't return exactly the value I need, eg: for the string `123;456;456` it returns `123;456;456`and for the string `123;123;123` it returns `123;123`

What I need is to return only the value for the `([0-9]+)` portion of the expression, from what I've read this would normally be done using non-capturing groups. But either I'm doing it wrong or Oracle SQL doesn't support this as if I try using the `?:` syntax the result is not what I expect.

Any suggestions on how you would go about this on oracle sql? The purpose of this expression is to use it on a query.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, "expression") FROM DUAL;
```

EDIT:

Actually according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

> Oracle Database implements regular expression support compliant with the POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE) specification.

Which according to https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

> Non-capturing group is not supported by POSIX ERE

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need a regular expression.  You need to fix your data model so you are not storing lists of numbers in a delimited string.

Comment: I know that storing the values like that is not optimal, but it's not my database so I can't just "fix the data model"

Comment: You didn't tell us what you want from the last row in your example: is `123` a repeated "string" in `123;456;123`? Separately, what if a string looks like `123;123;456;456`? What do you need returned - the FIRST substring (really, token) found in the string?

Comment: Also: are the double-quotes part of your strings, or did you just mean them as string delimiters? In Oracle the string delimiter is the single quote rather than the double quote.

Comment: So I thought this would be an interesting take (using purely regex) to do what I believe you want to do. Note that this uses PCRE regex and likely will not work in POSIX (by likely, I mean it doesn't), but, nevertheless, it does answer your question `"(?:(\d+);(?(?=\1)(?<duplicate>\d+)|(\d+));(?(?=\1|\2|\3)(?<duplicate>\d+)|(\d+)))"`. See it in use here: https://regex101.com/r/31WULs/1

Comment: Edited the question, `123;456;123` still contains `123` twice so expected result would be `123` as for `123;123;456;456` there can only be a maximum of 3 values so 2 different values can't be repeated on the same string

Comment: `(\d{3}).*\1` should work

Comment: Is it always 3 groups of 3 digits?

Comment: "...there can only be a maximum of 3 values..." >> You have to be careful with requirements like that. In my experience, a business rule is only true for as long as it takes someone else to decide they need a change.

Comment: @Shawn well, I'm talking about the set of strings i currently have, even if it changes in the future it won't affect what I'm trying to do right now.

Comment: @TheChetan definitely a more elegant expression, but as you can see the result is the same https://regex101.com/r/31WULs/2 what I need is for the expression to only return the value captured by group 1

Comment: According to https://regular-expressions.mobi/oracle.html?wlr=1, you can select the value of a particular group using `regex_substr`.  Use the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759146/4110233) describes how to select a matching group from a regex. So using that,

```
SELECT regexp_substr(column, '(\d{3}).*\1', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual;
#                                                       ^ Select group 1
```

[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/31WULs/2) of the regex (courtesy: OP).

Comment: Be careful, this matches 123 in  '123;456;123456'

Comment: I didn't know regexp_substr could take more parameters, that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish and I dun think I can find a better solution. Ty

Comment: @Gary_W in this scenario that's not an issue since all values separated by `;` have the same lenght, however if you could have values of different lengths, this expression would solve that issue: `((^|;)(\d+)).*\1(;|$)`

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez, actually your regex still matches `123;456;4123`, what you need is a `\b` before `\1`, Im not sure if its supported in this.

Comment: @Gary_W got me there again, I'm not sure how exactly \b works but it probably can be fixed in a different way. I'll try

Comment: @Gary_W got it `((^|;)(\d+));?(.*;)?\1(;|$)`

Comment: Now I realized that both `((^|;)(\d+)).*\b\1(;|$)` and `((^|;)(\d+));?(.*;)?\1(;|$)` match `1234;123;456` which is wrong

Comment: `(\b\d+\b).*\1` will work if `\b` works. `\b` is word break, it looks for word endings

Comment: @TheChetan that one doesn't work though (https://regex101.com/r/31WULs/3) but this one seems to work on any combination i've tried `((^|;)(\d+))(;.*)?;\3(;|$)` (https://regex101.com/r/31WULs/4)

Comment: Yeah that one works (https://regex101.com/r/31WULs/5) but, why does it work? what makes something qualify as a word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155873/discussion-between-thechetan-and-artemio-ramirez).

Answer (score 1):

If you only have three substrings, then you can use a brute force method.  It is not particularly pretty, but it should do the job:

```
select (case when val1 in (val2, val3) then val1
             when val2 = val3 then val2
        end) as repeated
from (select t.*,
             regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, 1) as val1,
             regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, 2) as val2,
             regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, 3) as val3
      from t
     ) t
where val1 in (val2, val3) or val2 = val3;
```

Comment: Right now I'm mostly curious as to wether it's possible to solve this with only a regular expression, but yeah it had to be bruteforced due to time constrains

Comment: I'm afraid your regex will fail if there is a NULL element.  Please use this form instead: `regexp_substr(col, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`.  See here for proof: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle/31464699#31464699

Comment: @Gary_W . . . It seems to work for me with empty values:  http://rextester.com/EKIXZ93706.

Comment: I stand corrected (for this example anyway)!  I will study your example, but would still suggest changing the regex for reasons in the link provided.  It still works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please bear with me and think of this different approach.  Look at the problem a little differently and break it down in a way that gives you more flexibility in how you you are able look at the data.  It may or may not apply to your situation, but hopefully should be interesting to keep in mind that there are always different ways to approach a problem.

What if you turned the strings into rows so you could do standard SQL against them?  That way you could not only count elements that repeat but perhaps apply aggregate functions to look for patterns across sets or something.

Consider this then.  The first Common Table Expression (CTE) builds the original data set.  The second one, tbl_split, turns that data into a row for each element in the list. Uncomment the select that immediately follows to see.  The last query selects from the split data, showing the count of how often the element occurs in the id's data.  Uncomment the HAVING line to restrict the output to those elements that appear more than one time for the data you are after.

With the data in rows you can see how other aggregate functions could be applied to slice and dice to reveal patterns, etc.

```
SQL> with tbl_orig(id, str) as (
     select 1, '123;456;789' from dual union all
     select 2, '123;123;456' from dual union all
     select 3, '123;123;123' from dual union all
     select 4, '123;456;456' from dual union all
     select 5, '123;456;123' from dual
   ),
   tbl_split(id, element) as (
   select id,
          regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) element
   from tbl_orig
   connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ';')+1
   and prior id = id
   and prior sys_guid() is not null
   )
   --select * from tbl_split;
   select distinct id, element, count(element)
   from tbl_split
   group by id, element
   --having count(element) > 1
   order by id;

        ID ELEMENT     COUNT(ELEMENT)
---------- ----------- --------------
         1 123                      1
         1 456                      1
         1 789                      1
         2 123                      2
         2 456                      1
         3 123                      3
         4 123                      1
         4 456                      2
         5 123                      2
         5 456                      1

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: You are right in that it's always nice to evaluate different approaches to things that may let you see things you might be missing. For my particular scenario though the answer I already marked still fita best. As I didn't need nor want to manipulate the data any further than identifying the rows with duplicate values in them and which value was the duplicate

Comment: See my edit at the bottom.  I'm saying this approach is another that can answer your question while setting a framework for looking at the data in different ways too. Just a approaching the problem a different way.