# What is equivalent of ?= in Oracle regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to write a regular expression in `regexp_substr()`.

For example, I have a string `DA.*BLK` and I want to extract whatever between `A` and `B`. What I am doing now is to use

```
replace(replace(regexp_substr(target_column,'A.*B'),'A',''),'B','')`
```

Then I get whatever is in between.

But I think this way may not be efficient and it's not elegant. I also tried to use `?=` in there but it seems Oracle does not support such clause.
Could any one please let me know a better way to achieve my purpose? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use `regexp_replace()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7758859/2422776 . Not voting to close as a duplicate so I won't dup-hammer by mistake.

Comment: Could you please show me an example?

Comment: What result do you require from a string like `'AAA123BBB'`?

Comment: @APC Very good point, thank you! I think if I have that kind of problem I would be more specific in terms of the number of A or B. For example, if I need `123`, I would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(AAA123BBB','AAA(.*)BBB', 1,1,NULL,1)` or I can use more neighboring characters to specify the boundary. But if you have better solutions please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use extract groups

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('DASOMETHINGBLK','DA(.*)BLK', 1,1,NULL,1)
               --                           ^ ^      ^
               --starting from first, find first     1st match bet'n ()
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/967

Comment: Definitely the neatest solution. However, note that this solution only works with the sixth parameter, subexpression, which was introduced in 11g. Also, it may not produce the expected result with a string like `'AAA123BBB'`

Comment: @APC Thank you for your comment as well. It's a very good point!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regular expressions, you can use the `LIKE` operator and string functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, column_name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'dablk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'datestblk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'atestblk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'datestbl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'dadatestblkblk' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query** - For strings starting with `da` and ending with `blk`:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR( column_name, 3, LENGTH( column_name ) - 5 )
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name LIKE 'da%blk';
```

**Results**:

```
ID | SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,3,LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME)-5)
---|--------------------------------------------
 1 | (null)
 2 | test
 5 | datestblk
```

**Query** - For strings with `a` then `b`:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(
         column_name,
         first_a + 1,
         last_b - first_a - 1
       ) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         INSTR( column_name, 'a' ) AS first_a,
         INSTR( column_name, 'b', -1 ) AS last_b
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  column_name LIKE '%a%b%'
)
```

**Results**:

```
ID | VALUE    
---|----------
 1 | (null)
 2 | test     
 3 | test     
 4 | test     
 5 | datestblk
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d986a93060dc10f3b69447f9ef041fe1)*