# Regex in redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift, regex-group

I have a problem.. I need to extract from this field:

```
exchange<=><br>type<=>full<br>cont<=>part<br>req<=>no<br>money<=>money<br>money<=>3100,4000,0,month<br>boss<=>0
```

five informations:

1. `full`
2. `part`
3. `3100`
   4.`4000`
   5.`month`

I have tried to use regexp_substr(): 
`regexp_substr(column,'type<=>[^<br>]*')` but I dont have any knowledge about regex and I cant do it in a properly way.. can you help me with that?

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(column,'type<=>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)')` or try `[^<]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: yes it works for type and cont :) my results (type<=>full) and (cont<=>part), but it doesnt work from 3100, 4000 and month..

Comment: Aha, so you want separate regexps, right? `regexp_substr(column,'type<=>([^<]+)')`, `regexp_substr(column,'cont<=>([^<]+)')`, then `money<=>([0-9]+)`, `money<=>[0-9]+,([0-9]+)` and `money<=>[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,([^<]+)`

Comment: when it comes to : `money<=>([0-9]+)` <- it works properly but others not.. when it comes to `4000` my input : `money<=>3500,4000` and when it comes to `month` my input : `money<=>3100,4000,0,month`

Comment: Are you sure you are placing the capturing parentheses where I put them?

Comment: yes -> copy paste method :)

Comment: Well, see https://regex101.com/r/o6vCPT/1,  https://regex101.com/r/o6vCPT/2 and  https://regex101.com/r/o6vCPT/3 - the green highlighted text must be what you get.

Comment: I got not green but blue highlighted text - (full match):(

Comment: Useful for Redshift: [Extract data in parentheses with Amazon-redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54922350/174777)

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with redshift but with regex I can help you:

```
"(type|cont|money)<=>([^<,]+)(,([^<,]+),[^<,]+,([^<,]+))?"
```

The capture number 4 in the string you put as an example it will capture all you need, it even exclude the 0 :

Group 1:    money
Group 2:    3100
Group 3:    ,4000,0,month
Group 4:    4000
Group 5:    month

In case you have problems, tell me.
If you want to master your regex skills I can teach you, it will be useful.

Comment: wait, I will fix it

Comment: Look at this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle

You have to specify the capturing group you want, in that case is the second , I gess, because I can not try this regex in redshift

Comment: In the last case you need to specify that you want the group 2 , 4 and 5

Comment: Here is explained better : 
https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/character-functions/oracle-regexp_substr-function.php