# Extract data in parentheses with Amazon-redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have these characters in a table:

```
LEASE THIRD-CCP-MANAGER (AAAA)
THE MANAGEMENT OF A THIRD PARTY (BBBB / AAAA)
```

When I extract the information:

```
AAAA
BBBB/AAAA
```

That is, I have to look for the pattern and extract what is inside the parenthesis.

I'm trying to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function.

In amazon redshift, how do I extract the characters in parentheses?

thanks

Comment: Show what you’ve tried, what the problem is, etc

Comment: regexp_substr(column,'\([^\)]*').  Error:  Unmatched marking parenthesis ( or \(.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '([^)]*>>>HERE>>>'.

Comment: As per my answer, you need to escape the brackets...

Answer (score 4):

Whoa, that was hard!

Here is the syntax to use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('One (Two) Three', '[(](.*)[)]', 1, 1, 'e')
```

This will return: `Two`

It appears that escaping brackets with `\(` doesn't work, but putting them in `[(]` does work. The `'e'` at the end will "Extract a substring using a subexpression".

Answer (score 0):

use `position` for finding the index of parenthesis `(`   and then `substring`

```
select 
substring(position('(' in 'LEASE THIRD-CCP-MANAGER (AAAA)'),position(')' in 'LEASE THIRD-CCP-MANAGER (AAAA)'))
```

or you can use `split_part`

```
split_part('LEASE THIRD-CCP-MANAGER (AAAA)','(',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably struggling with `()` meaning something in regular expressions (lookup “back references”)

To tell regex that you just mean the characters `(` and `)` without their special meaning, “escape” them using `\`

```
regexp_substr(yourtable.yourcolumn,'\(.*\)')
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have tried, but it does not extract the information.
I tried split_part, but I would like to do it with regular expressions.
SPLIT_PART (SPLIT_PART (EXAMPLE_COLUMN, '(', 2), ')', 1)

Comment: @dapdap Seems to work for me : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b32/2909 (I know it's oracle, but the syntax is the same as redshift)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.

What do the parameters 1 and 2 mean?

Comment: @dapdap Ummm, that you can find out just by reading the online help. You DID try reading the online help?