# How to extract the package name using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I'd like to extract the package name using regexp_substr.

For example:

> create or replace package body something.pkg_test is

I want that:

> pkg_test

I tried to use lookbehind just to ignore "create or replace package body something.":

```
select regexp_substr('create or replace package body something.pkg_test is','((?<!create\sor\sreplace\spackage\sbody\ssomething\.).)*$',1,1) from dual;
```

But it doesn’t work. So I just need to extract the package name between "create or replace package body something" and the first space or \n.

I need that because I want the package name before compile a .sql file and insert it in a table.

Comment: If you want to check a package name, why not do a simple `like` check instead of extracting with regexp? `if line like 'create%or%replace%package%body%something.pkg_test%' then ...`. It's not as fool-proof but should do fine for your purpose.

Comment: I want to extract the package name and insert it in a table before compile. I just have the .sql file. I don't know what is the package name. I change the word "check" just to "want the package name"

Comment: You may also want to consider the optional keywords `EDITIONABLE` and `NONEDITIONABLE`.  Even though almost nobody cares about them, a lot of tools automatically generate them and they may show up in DDL.

Comment: @JonHeller you have a point. I‘ll consider it now I know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that, maybe you are trying to write some expression with positive look-behind:

```
(?<=create\sor\sreplace\spackage\sbody\ssomething\.)\S*
```

---

Or maybe, alternatively, we'd use some expression without lookarounds, such as:

```
create\sor\sreplace\spackage\sbody\ssomething\.(\S*).*
```

with capturing group `1`, and our code might look like:

```
select regexp_replace('create or replace package body something.pkg_test is', 'create\sor\sreplace\spackage\sbody\ssomething\.(\S*).*', '\1') from dual;
```

not sure though.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cIPRTV/1/)

---

#### Demo

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZPXBwH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ZPXBwH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### Reference

[How to extract group from regular expression in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle)

Comment: This work in your link, but it doesn't work with regexp_subst. I don't know why.