# SQL Query to select a string between two characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve a String between two characters.
I have whole string like "*Attachments:Attachments~Attachment*" and I want to take substring between **:** and **~** characters that is output will be *Attachments*.
How can be this done in SQL/Oracle select statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function. Starting with Oracle 11g, there is a parameter to the function, which lets you specify the capture group that you want returned:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment', '\:(.+)\~', 1,1,NULL,1) from dual;
```

There are workarounds for older versions (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759146/14015737). You can shorten your result:

```
SELECT rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment', '\:(.+)\~'),':'), '~') FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT substr( match, 2, length(match)-2 ) from (
SELECT regexp_substr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment', '\:(.+)\~') match FROM dual);
```