# Get 5 Characters After Last Slash

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need the first 5 characters after the last slash. I can handle to get all symbols after slash, but fail to take only the first 5 of them.

```
REGEX_SUBSTR('people/capital/base/flagedbyloggers','[^/]*$')
```

With `[^/]*$`, I get `flagedbyloggers`, but I need only `flaged`, first 5 symbols.

With `[^/]{5}$`, I get `ggers`, which is 5 last symbols after the last slash, but I need  `flaged`, first 5 symbols after the last slash.

Also sometimes the string after last slash can be shorter, so it has to work with less then 5 characters, e.g. `people/capital/base/no` should return only `no`.

The environment is ORACLE database. Same result I have with online tool https://regexr.com/ .

Comment: What is the environment? Try [`([^/]{6})[^/]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Fc0cAi/2)

Comment: I think you need 6 characters right? `^.*\/(.{6})` https://regex101.com/r/ysmdud/1

Comment: _"I don't think environment matters"_ It _does_ matter. Whenever you post a regex question, it's important to include the programming language, tool, or regex flavor that you're using. That's because not all regex features are supported by all flavors. Syntax can be different too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match until the last occurrence of a `/` with a capturing group and a  quantifier `{1,6}` to match `no` or `flaged`

**Note** that `flaged` are 6 characters instead of 5 after the `/`

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle) shows how to get the capturing group from the match using either [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099) or [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490).

```
^.*/([^/]{1,6})[^/]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*/` Make sure to match the last occurrence of `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^/]{1,6}` Match 6 times any char other than `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^/]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `/`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQo4C6/1)

Comment: That works for all scenarios, thank you. Also looks like that mine regex demo site works incorrectly, so I will start to use your for demo/testing regex.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression. You can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, INSTR( value, '/', -1 ) + 1, 6 ) AS substring
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'people/capital/base/flagedbyloggers' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | SUBSTRING |
> | :-------- |
> | flaged    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=58c164c778485a75fad93447a9319ceb)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prefer regex, because they are universal and can be reused in backend/frontend code. +1

Comment: @TPAKTOPA They are not guaranteed to be universal; Oracle does not support the full range of regular expression syntax (for example, you cannot use non-capturing groups or match on word boundaries). String functions are pretty universal, they may have different names between front- and back-end but when you know what you want to achieve then finding a substring of length 6 starting at the character after the index of the last slash character is going to be pretty easy to translate from Oracle database to Python/Java/C++/etc. (middle-tier) to JavaScript (client-side).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) code:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR('people/capital/base/flagedbyloggers', '([^/]{1,6})[^/]*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fc0cAi/3). Details:

- `([^/]{1,6})` - one to six chars other than `/` (Group 1, the last argument in the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` extracts this value)
- `[^/]*$` - any zero or more chars other than `/` up to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it works for long last string, but not for a shorter one. Also, parameters for function helped. +1

Comment: @TPAKTOPA I changed the quantifier. It was actually not a problem since the solution worked for the current OP.

Comment: My bad, I edited post and added later, that it should work with shorter text too.

Answer (score 1):

If except slash characters are words, you can use the below statement.

```regex
/(\w{5})\w*$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eiWG4H/1/)