# How to extract a text between brackets in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract a value between the brackets from a string.

For example, I have this string:

```
No information was found [AI1234].
```

And I want to get the result between the brackets, i.e. `AI1234`.

However the expression is not always the same. It may vary.

I am trying to write a query like this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(mssg, '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS "description" from book
```

But it is not returning anything.What am I missing?

Also I already tried something like that, the things is that the bracket length may vary. So this one below will return something, but not what I am looking for:

```
substr(mssg,instr(mssg,'(')-8,10) as "description"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do googling more about oracle regexp.

Please try with this.(above Oracle 11g)

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(mssg, '\[[^0-9]*(\d+)[^0-9]*\]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) description
FROM book;
```

** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758859/how-to-extract-group-from-regular-expression-in-oracle) helped me to answer here.

> UPDATE: This will be OK.
>
> ```sql
> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('No information was found [{AI1234}].', '[[({][^0-9]*(\d+)[^0-9]*[]})]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) description
> FROM dual;
> ```

**UPDATE: Final solution**

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('No information was found [{AI1234}].', '[[({]+([^][)(}{]*)[])}]+', 1, 1, NULL, 1) description
FROM dual;
```

Here, you should take care to `[^][)(}{]`. 
***DO NOT*** swap the bracket chracters.
I'll quote from [Oracle 11g Regexp reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540)

> `[ ]`
>
> Bracket expression for specifying a matching list that should match any one of the expressions represented in the list. A non-matching list expression begins with a circumflex (^) and specifies a list that matches any character except for the expressions represented in the list.
>
> **To specify a right bracket (]) in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (^), if any).**
>
> To specify a hyphen in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (^), if any), last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.

This part - `[^ ]` - was a hard nut to crack and finally I found solution from the reference, that's why I emphasis this.

Comment: what about if I also have letters inside those brackets? It not returning the ones that have letters and numbers inside the bracket.  Also, what if I need the 3rd bracket from the message? Thank you

Comment: @user16523359 I tested and updated, this maybe what you wanted.

Comment: The updated code is only returning the numbers 1234, but not the letters AI.

Comment: @user16523359 Ahh, you mean all the letters in the brackets, not only digits? yeah, I'll correct it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one last question.  What if I have more than one bracket and I want to obtain the information not from the first bracket but from the last.  I can have up to 3 brackets, but always want to return the information from the last bracket . For example see below: 
'No information was found [AI1234].ValueR =[ABC123]. id [CD23478]' and I want everything that is inside the last bracket, so CD23478
THANK YOU!!

Comment: @user16523359 try this `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('No information was found [AI1234].ValueR =[ABC123]. id [CD23478]', '[[({]+([^][)(}{]*)[])}]+[^][)(}{]*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) description
FROM dual;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a group of digits between square brackets, try this:

```
WITH
indata(msg) AS (
  SELECT 'No information was found [1234]'
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
     msg                    -- the string
   , '^[^[]+[[](\d+)[]].*$' -- the pattern (with a captured
                            -- string "\d+" in round parentheses)
   , 1                      -- start from position 1
   , 1                      -- first found occurrence
   , ''                     -- no modifiers
   , 1                      -- first captured group
   ) AS extr
FROM indata;
 extr 
------
 1234
```